# How to set log folder for log4j2 relative in tomcat8?

Tags: java, log4j2, tomcat8

I'm running a `spring-boot` `*.war` application in a `tomcat8` server.

I configured the following logpath in `log4j2.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
<Appenders>
  <RollingRandomAccessFile name="APP" fileName="logs/myapplication.log"
                                 filePattern="logs/archive/myapplication-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
```

Result:
I can see the `myapplication.log` in `/var/log/tomcat8/`, BUT there is no subfolder `/logs`.

Question: I would expect the logs being placed under `/var/log/tomcat8/logs`, as I configured this path. But that's not the case. Further, there is also no `/archive` folder inside, so the rolling file does also not work.

But why? What might be missing?

Running on linux ubuntu 16.

Comment: is it possible that the `myapplication.log` to be there from an earlier attempt and the whole `logs` folder to don't be generated? Or do you see any new changes in this `.log` file?

Comment: Yes I see changes to it. Strange that is goes into the root of the log folder even though I configured the subfolder `/logs/`...

Comment: Do I maybe have to use pathvariable `${catalina.base}` or similar in the configuration?

Comment: is your `log4j2.xml` in your classpath? as from: `Log4j will provide a default configuration if it cannot locate a configuration file. The default configuration, provided in the DefaultConfiguration class, will set up:
    A ConsoleAppender attached to the root logger.
    A PatternLayout set to the pattern "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" attached to the ConsoleAppender` seems that if your config file isn't right configured a default logger will be created that outputs in the root (source: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

Comment: All in all I have 3 different appenders, and I can see those 3 logfiles with the correct content logged. So I assume in general the configuration is correctly picked up. Just the path not.

Comment: try to use the properties and set a variable, maybe this way it works: `<Properties>
    <Property name="filename">logs/myapplication.log</Property>
</Properties>` and then use `fileName="${filename}"`

Comment: Unfortunately this is also not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147594/discussion-between-edwin-and-membersound).